# Ruby Capybara handling alert/loading screen

Tags: rubygems, cucumber, capybara, browser-automation

We are using Ruby Cucumber framework.

Below is the code for clicking an button

```
 click_on(button_text)
```

but when it clicks on a button in our application, a loading screen appears.

[image]

and it throws below error message

```
unexpected alert open
 (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.94)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
```

Please do let me know how can we handle it

Answer (score 0):

"unexpected alert open" would generally indicate a modal alert box has opened on the page, not a JS driven loading indicator.  Are you sure it's not opening a confirm, prompt, or alert??  If it is then you handle it like

```
accept_alert do
  click_on(button_text)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with all the options like accept_alert, page.driver.wait_until(page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.dismiss) e.t.c

but some how wait for 15 seconds has worked for me.